# Android actoin bar get valules from linked layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

My android application has an action bar item to add employees.

[image]

So here what I did is call custom layout named add_employee when this action bar item clicked.

```
  <item android:id="@+id/action_add"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_add_person"
      android:title="@string/action_add"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" 
      android:actionLayout="@layout/add_employee"/>
```

Following image shows that custom layout:

[image]

This is a loyout xml file named add_employee. Add and cross marks are image views.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_cancel" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="228dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/addemp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add_person" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now I want to get the entered value to this edit text field when add image view clicked. This operation should be handled in the same java class where I set the option menu also.

```
public class MainPortal extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_portal);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_portal, menu);
     return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
   }
}
```

I have used `setOnItemClickListener` for imge view but it ends with a forced closed error. How can I do this task?
Please help me...
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the actions in  `onOptionsItemSelected`? Where is the code showing the implementation of the Action bar tabs?

this is how to implement an option on actionbar

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            openSearch();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_compose:
            composeMessage();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

there you can implement whatever and however...
plus showing more code and LogCat would help understanding your exact issue